# How to rewrite capistrano 2 task with `exception` to capistarano 3

Tags: capistrano

I want to rewrite a capistrano 2 task in a way capistrano 3.

This code is from [Railscast 335](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)

```
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end
```

I can rewrite according to the document of capistrano like this.

```
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
     desc "#{command} unicorn server"
     task command do
        on roles(:app) do
          run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
        end
     end
  end
```

But I have no idea how to rewrite `except: {no_release: true}` part, and I couldn't find document about it.

How can I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1):

```
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
     desc "#{command} unicorn server"
     task command do
        on roles(:app), reject: lambda { |h| h.properties.no_release } do
          run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
        end
     end
  end
```

More info: http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html